# Unlock an ssh private key with a biometric token instead of a passphrase

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, fingerprint

I have private ssh keys that are protected by a passphrase. Is it possible to unlock those keys with some biometric token, in particular my personal fingerprint, instead of the passphrase?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I haven enabled fingerprint login in the settings
[image: screenshot of fingerprint login in ubuntu settings]

Also, I have used [pam-auth-update](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pam-auth-update.8.html#:%7E:text=pam%2Dauth%2Dupdate%20is%20a,supplied%20by%20PAM%20module%20packages.) to control some settings of what I can unlock with my fingerprint.

Comment: This is 100% on topic and welcome here, but I suspect you might have better chances of getting an answer over at [ubuntu.se]. You might want to think about deleting this and reposting there since that's where most of the Ubuntu people hang out and this is likely to involve Ubuntu-specific features. Up to you!